# How to log objects as json with JsonConsole in .NET 6 without escaping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, .net-6.0

I want to log some objects as JSON but I have some escaping problems with JsonConsole in .NET 6

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logginBuilder =>
    {
        logginBuilder.ClearProviders();
        logginBuilder.AddJsonConsole(jsonConsoleFormatterOptions => 
        {
            jsonConsoleFormatterOptions.JsonWriterOptions = new()
            {
                Indented = true,
                Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
            };
        });
    })
    .Build();

var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
AvailableFlight availableFlight = new()
{
    DepartureDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
    AirlineName = "Saha",
    Destination = "KIH",
    Origin = "THR"
};


logger.LogInformation("Available Flight: {AvailableFlight}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(availableFlight));

await host.RunAsync();


public class AvailableFlight
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string AirlineName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DepartureDate { get; set; }
}
```

The actual output is:

```
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Program","Message":"Available Flight: {\"Origin\":\"THR\",\"Destination\":\"KIH\",\"AirlineName\":\"Saha\",\"DepartureDate\":\"2022-01-09T22:27:21.2981943+03:30\"}","State":{"Message":"Available Flight: {\"Origin\":\"THR\",\"Destination\":\"KIH\",\"AirlineName\":\"Saha\",\"DepartureDate\":\"2022-01-09T22:27:21.2981943+03:30\"}","AvailableFlight":"{\"Origin\":\"THR\",\"Destination\":\"KIH\",\"AirlineName\":\"Saha\",\"DepartureDate\":\"2022-01-09T22:27:21.2981943+03:30\"}","{OriginalFormat}":"Available Flight: {AvailableFlight}"}}
```

[image: output of UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping]

How can I prevent these double quotes from escaping?

I want this:

```
{"prop":"value"}
```

Instead of:

```
{\"prop\":\"value\"}
```

Comment: it looks like your `Message` string has json embedded in it. what would you expect in this case?

Comment: You are talking about nested JSON strings. It will be an invalid JSON if you remove that escaping. So the only way would be removing those nested JSON strings and maintaining regular JSON structure

Comment: @DanielA.White yes my message has json in it

Comment: you could use a different log formatter

Comment: @AndrewSilver I got it thank you

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok, so I need to write a custom ConsoleFormatter

Comment: It seems that only option here is to write [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#implement-a-custom-formatter)